# Dark theme also for mobile view

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, dark-mode

On the desktop version of Stack Overflow, the dark theme works, however, on a tablet with the mobile version the dark mode of the device is not respected - the only way to get it is to request the desktop version which is not optimal on a mobile device.

Can you please also introduce the dark mode for the mobile variant?

Update: In Mobile Firefox 86.0 for the responsive mobile version there is no dark theme.

Comment: I'm talking about the responsive webpage theme.

Comment: There is dark theme support for the **responsive** view. The mobile view on the other hand, has been abandoned and is best avoided.  Wonder why is still around. The responsive one (the one you get when you click on “full site”) is much better all around.

Comment: The mobile view has just received a top bar redesign. It is probably not completely abandoned.

Comment: I'm on a mobile phone now, trying to get dark theme. How would I get the responsive view?

Comment: The dark theme is displayed if one does a search other than a tagged question if on the desktop website via a mobile device. But, say if there is a search by using a tag or requesting the mobile website, the theme will not be shown.